# What's the best way to attach an object to a logical control flow?

Tags: c#, multithreading, iidentity

I need to make an object statically available for:

(1) the current thread on which my program is running
(2) all threads started by that thread
(3) all thread pool tasks enqueued by that thread

One way I've figured out to do this is to use a ConditionalWeakTable keyed on `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity`, since that object (when set) seems to be passed around appropriately by the .NET framework. However, I'm wondering (1) are there any limitations/problems with this approach? and (2) is there another cleaner approach to solving this problem that is already built into the .NET framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found do do this was to use the "LogicalCallContext". Basically, I maintain a static `ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, MyObject>`, and the use `CallContext.Logical[Get|Set]Data("uniqueStringKey", guid);` to associate guids with particular logical control flows. I've found this to work correctly with both manually created threads and the thread pool.